# Como obter o nome de uma seção que contém uma String

Tags: java, spring, yaml

O código serve para pegar todas as seções no arquivo YML, até ai está funcionando, mas não sei como pegar o a seção que contém o nome "Fulano", por exemplo:

```
Grupos:
 Usuário:
   pessoas:
   - Fulano
 Dono:
   pessoas:
```

Código para pegar todas as seções:

```
for (String grupos : ConfigManager.get("arquivo.yml").getConfigurationSection("Grupos")
                        .getKeys(false)) {
}
```

Eu queria que verificasse todos os grupos e retornasse o nome do grupo que contém o nome "Fulano"
Porém não faço a miníma ideia de como fazer, podem me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Esta classe `ConfigManager` é do Spring?